# С++ указатель на указатель на класс

Tags: c++, visual-c++

помогите решить возникшую проблему:
Есть иерархия классов CBullet -> CSplashBullet -> CFireBullet.
есть функция, которая возвращает указатель на базовый (CBullet) класс:

```
CBullet* CTower::fireInTheHole(DRAQON* target, SDL_Texture* tex)
{
    switch (this->type)
    {
    case TOWER_FIRE:
        SDL_Rect tempRect;
        tempRect.x = 0;
        tempRect.y = 0;
        tempRect.w = 32;
        tempRect.h = 32;
        return &CFireBullet(tex, this->x, this->y, 10, 1, &tempRect, target, this->splash);
        break;
    }
}
```

дальше в функции main:

```
std::cout << "close1" << std::endl;
CBullet* testBullet = towerIterator->fireInTheHole(&draqotest, bulletTexture);
CBullet** ptrptr = &testBullet;
testBullet->fly();
std::cout << "close1-2" << std::endl;
(*ptrptr)->fly();
std::cout << "close2" << std::endl;
```

testBullet->fly(); вызывается нормально. "close1-2" выводится, а на (*ptrptr)->fly(); прога крашится.

вот описание самого метода fly()

```
void CFireBullet::fly()
{
    std::cout << "CFireBullet::fly" << std::endl;
    double angle = atan2(target->y - this->y, target->x - this->x);
    this->x += cos(angle) * this->speed;
    this->y += sin(angle) * this->speed;
}
```

Зачем мне нужен указатель на указатель? Дело в том, что у меня есть list<CBullet*> и при попытка обращения к объекту через итератор (что, по сути, является указателем на указатель на объект) происходит точно такой же краш проги.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, в `CTower::fireInTheHole` вы возвращаете указатель на дохлый объект `CFireBullet`. Добро пожаловать в мир memory corruption! Это должно быть корневой проблемой.

Дело в том, что код

```
&CFireBullet(tex, this->x, this->y, 10, 1, &tempRect, target, this->splash)
```

создаёт временный объект, который умрёт, когда строка отработает. Не делайте так, воспользуйтесь честным `new`. Не забудьте освободить объект, когда он вам больше не будет нужен.

Comment: Спасибо! Похоже, что это решила проблему (во всяком случае прога перестала вылетать, правда и не выполняет весь функционал, что нужно было). сейчас нет времени дебажить, поэтому просто спрошу на будущее: как мне потом очищать list с этими указателями на базовый класс? если внутри самих классов память нигде не выделяется, то подойдет ли такой способ:
for (bulletIterator = bullet_list.begin(); bulletIterator != bullet_list.end(); bulletIterator++)
 {
  delete (*bulletIterator);
 }
??

Comment: @melodicwing: Да, так сработает. Концептуально правильнее, однако, пользоваться `shared_ptr` и тому подобными штуками: они удалят объект автоматически.